# Add value from InputBox to objFSO.OpenTextFile in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

## My Question

I keep getting an error here, the objective of this program is to read a file type I made (.ptaf Plain Text Archive Format) but it keeps returning this error:

***Variable is undefined: "Input"***

## The Code

```
 Option Explicit

Const conForReading = 1

'Declare variables
Dim objFSO, objReadFile, contents
```

### Problem Area

```
'Input
Input = InputBox("Please enter the path of the file you want to open:", _
    "Open Plain Text Archive File File")

'Set Objects
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\MyArchives\"& Input.Value , 1, False)
```

### End Of Problem Area

```
'Read file contents
contents = objReadFile.ReadAll

'Close file
objReadFile.close

'Display results
wscript.echo contents

'Cleanup objects
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objReadFile = Nothing

     Thanks,
     -------
         Mr.Minecrafter
         --------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try below

```
Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\MyArchives\"& Input, 1, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `Dim` the variable `Input` (and follow @AshReva's advice - `Input` is not an object).